# Stretching an img by setting it's height/width at runtime using CSS produces odd gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the gradient on the right hand side of the popup in this image: http://s29.postimg.org/gvr8liupj/lv_problem.jpg

The left, top and bottom edges of the 'popup' (an absolutely positioned div) are stretched in exactly the same way - I simply set the width/height at run-time using jQuery...

I've checked everything and am stumped.  Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: What you're asking leaves too many things to the imagination. Can you provide a code sample of how the 'popup' as you say is generated?

Answer (score 0):

The gradient is part of the image. To remove the gradient you need to edit the image.